# Objective C: replacing a synchronous request

Tags: objective-c, nsurlconnection, objective-c-blocks, nsurlsession

I'm having problem replacing this code.

```
-(NSMutableArray *) GetPrices: {

    NSError *error;
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSData *tw_result = [NSURLConnection       
       sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest 
       returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

The problem I have is that the function that calls this code process the url and then returns data to a method that calls it.

Previously I used this like so.

ViewController calls a function to gather data by creating an operation queue (so that the UI & main thread are available)

```
     NSOperationQueue *myQueue = [NSOperationQueue new];
      NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc]
 initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(loadDataWithOperation) object:nil];
                [myQueue addOperation:operation];
                [operation release];
                [myQueue release];
```

The function in the operation queue calls the method to get data on an object and that method then runs the synchronous URLrequest.

```
-(void)loadDataWithOperation {

    self.sectionPriceArray = [self.myObject GetPrices];
```

So myObject would return a price array.

I have tried using NSSession but but I can't figure out how to pass the result back as the method terminates prior to getting tw_result from the completion Handler.

Any thoughts I have to do this in Objective C as I don't have permission from the client to convert to swift.

EDIT of Question with more details:

Inside my GetPrices method I have tried

```
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
        [[session dataTaskWithRequest:urlRequest
                    completionHandler:^(NSData *tw_result,
                                        NSURLResponse *response,
                                        NSError *error) {
                        result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:tw_result encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSArray *resultArray = [result componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
        }) resume];
```

But I cannot figure out how to make this work one level up at the calling level.

Comment: You need to refactor your code to properly work with asynchronous requests.

Comment: Yes: I guess I'm having difficulty deciding the design pattern also do you have any examples that are similar ?

Comment: You want a method with a completion handler, not a return value. There are countless examples in the iOS/macOS APIs.

Comment: I edited my question, I have looked at using the NSURLSession but the problem is getting data back I haven't figured that out at there next level up.  I have looked at many examples but can't quite apply them here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @maddy mentioned you're going to want to use a completion block for your getPrices method instead of a return -- returns + async don't mix.

This would be the general form to convert your getPrices method to:

```
- (void)_getPricesWithCompletion:(void(^)(NSMutableArray *sectionPriceArray))priceCompletion;
```

This site: http://goshdarnblocksyntax.com has some of the common block syntax declaration usages.

Typically you'd call this async method and then set your iVar in the completion block and reload your associated UI elements after receiving the new data.  Something along these lines:

```
[self _getPricesWithCompletion:^(NSMutableArray *sectionPriceArray) {
    self.sectionPriceArray = sectionPriceArray;
    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
        // reload any UI elements dependent on your sectionPriceArray here
    }];
}];
```

Now in the example code you show, it seems like you're using an NSOperationQueue to queue up different operations.  Things can get a bit more complicated here.  Subsequent queue'd operations won't wait on your async operations to finish before executing.  So for example, if you have an operation after the `getPrices` operation which utilizes the result of the fetch of the prices, the iVar will almost definitely not contain the correct data at that point.  In this case you'd need to use some sort of semaphore to handle waiting for the async operation to complete before continuing to the operation which depends upon it.

Here's an example of what I mean:

NotProperlyWaiting.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface NotProperlyWaiting : NSObject
@property (strong, nullable) NSMutableArray *sectionPriceArray;
- (void)callOperations;
- (void)fakeServerCallWithCompletion:(void(^)(NSData *tw_result, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error))completion;
@end
```

NotProperlyWaiting.m

```
#import "NotProperlyWaiting.h"

@interface NotProperlyWaiting()
- (void)_getPricesWithCompletion:(void(^)(NSMutableArray *sectionPriceArray))priceCompletion;
- (void)_printPricesArray;
@end

@implementation NotProperlyWaiting

- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _sectionPriceArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)callOperations {
    // setup our completion block to be passed in (this is what will eventually set the self.sectionPricesArray
    void (^pricesCompletion)(NSMutableArray *) = ^ void (NSMutableArray *sectionPricesArrayFromCompletion){
        self.sectionPriceArray = sectionPricesArrayFromCompletion;
    };
    NSOperationQueue *myQueue = [NSOperationQueue new];
    NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(_getPricesWithCompletion:) object:pricesCompletion];
    NSInvocationOperation *printOperation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(_printPricesArray) object:nil];
    [myQueue addOperation:operation];
    [myQueue addOperation:printOperation];
}

- (void)_getPricesWithCompletion:(void(^)(NSMutableArray *sectionPricesArray))priceCompletion {
    [self fakeServerCallWithCompletion:^(NSData *tw_result, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        // check the error or response or whatever else to verify that the data is legit from your server endpoint here
        // then convert the data to your mutable array and pass it through to our completion block
        NSString *stringData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:tw_result encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSMutableArray *tempPricesArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[stringData componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"]];
        // now our completion block passing in the result prices array
        priceCompletion(tempPricesArray);
    }];
}

- (void)_printPricesArray {
    NSLog(@"NotWaiting -- Prices array : %@", self.sectionPriceArray);
}

// this is a fake version of NSURLSession
- (void)fakeServerCallWithCompletion:(void(^)(NSData *tw_result, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error))completion {
    NSString *fakeServerResponse = @"FirstThing\nSecondThing\nThirdThing";
    NSData *fakeData = [fakeServerResponse dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSURLResponse *fakeResponse = [[NSURLResponse alloc] init];
    NSError *fakeError = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"FakeErrorDomain" code:33 userInfo:nil];
    // never call sleep in your own code, this is just to simulate the wait time for the server to return data
    sleep(3);
    completion(fakeData,fakeResponse,fakeError);
}

    NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

ProperlyWaiting.h (Subclass of NotProperlyWaiting.h to re-use callOperation and fakeServerCallWithCompletion:)

```
#import "NotProperlyWaiting.h"

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface ProperlyWaiting : NotProperlyWaiting

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

ProperlyWaiting.m

```
#import "ProperlyWaiting.h"

@interface ProperlyWaiting()
- (void)_getPricesWithCompletion:(void(^)(NSMutableArray *sectionPricesArray))priceCompletion;
- (void)_printPricesArray;
@property dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore;
@end

@implementation ProperlyWaiting

- (void)callOperations {
    self.semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
    [super callOperations];
}

// identical implementations to NotProperlyWaiting, but this time we'll use a semaphore to ensure the _printPricesArray waits for the async operation to complete before continuing
- (void)_getPricesWithCompletion:(void(^)(NSMutableArray *sectionPricesArray))priceCompletion {
    [self fakeServerCallWithCompletion:^(NSData *tw_result, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        // check the error or response or whatever else to verify that the data is legit from your server endpoint here
        // then convert the data to your mutable array and pass it through to our completion block
        NSString *stringData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:tw_result encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSMutableArray *tempPricesArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[stringData componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"]];
        // now our completion block passing in the result prices array
        priceCompletion(tempPricesArray);
        // signal our semaphore to let it know we're done
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(self.semaphore);
    }];
}

- (void)_printPricesArray {
    // wait for the semaphore signal before continuing (so we know the async operation we're waiting on has completed)
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(self.semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    NSLog(@"Waiting -- Prices array : %@", self.sectionPriceArray);
}

@end
```

With example calls of the class like this:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    NotProperlyWaiting *notWaiting = [[NotProperlyWaiting alloc] init];
    [notWaiting callOperations];

    ProperlyWaiting *waiting = [[ProperlyWaiting alloc] init];
    [waiting callOperations];
}
```

The output in the log will be:

```
NotWaiting -- Prices array : (
)
```

And then 3 seconds later:

```
Waiting -- Prices array : (
    FirstThing,
    SecondThing,
    ThirdThing
)
```

Some additional links to helpful documentation related to this topic:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/1452955-dispatch_semaphore_create

Comment: Wow thank you I have seen references to all of these concepts just couldn't figure out how to string them together, fantastic answer I'll give it a shot with fresh eyes today.

Comment: Thankyou.  Here's what I actually did as a result of your input.  1. I moved the actual URL request to the view controller and then I wasn't nesting the asynch calls and everything worked. I will try the NSoperation queue later once I have gotten everything stable

Comment: Glad to hear the example helped you get it working.  It's always good to keep things simple if possible (i.e. KISS principle https://effectivesoftwaredesign.com/2013/08/05/simplicity-in-software-design-kiss-yagni-and-occams-razor/)